# bash complete from two sources, folders and keys from array

Tags: bash

I am trying to define a bash function, `mycd`. This function uses an associative array `mycdar`. If the key exists in the array the function will change directory to the corresponding value of the key. If the key doesn't exist it will change to the dir provided in the command line.

What I would like to do is to have completion for this function, from both they keys of the associated array or from the folders existing in the current directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Would not `$CDPATH` be satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Building my own `cd` function with completion

Using an *associative array* for storing some paths.

First the command:

```
mycd() { [ -v mycdar["$1"] ] && cd "${mycdar[$1]}" || cd "$1"; }
```

Second the completion command

```
_mycd() {
    local cur;
    _cd ;
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur;
    COMPREPLY=($(
        printf "%s\n" "${!mycdar[@]}" |
            grep ^$cur)
        ${COMPREPLY[@]});
    }
```

One array:

```
declare -A mycdar='(
     ["docs"]="/usr/share/doc"
     ["home"]="$HOME"
     ["logs"]="/var/log"
     ["proc"]="/proc"
     ["root"]="/"
     ["tmp"]="/tmp"
)'
```

Than finaly the bind:

```
complete -F _mycd -o nospace mycd
```

Or to permit standard *path building* behaviour:

```
complete -F _mycd -o nospace -o plusdirs mycd
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is an option that to the complete function that does exactly what is asked:

```
complete -o plusdirs -o nospace -F _mycd mycd
```

In this case `_mycd` just returns matching elements from the keys of the associative array.