# What is the difference between using `sh` and `source`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

What is the difference between `sh` and `source`?

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Read and execute commands from FILENAME and return.  The pathnames
    in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.  If any
    ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
    FILENAME is executed.
```

And for `man sh`:

```
NAME
       bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell

SYNOPSIS
       bash [options] [file]

COPYRIGHT
       Bash is Copyright (C) 1989-2004 by the Free Software Foundation, Inc.

DESCRIPTION
       Bash  is  an sh-compatible command language interpreter that executes commands read from the standard input or from a file.  Bash also incorporates
       useful features from the Korn and C shells (ksh and csh).

       Bash is intended to be a conformant implementation of the IEEE POSIX Shell and Tools specification (IEEE Working Group 1003.2).
```

Comment: Notice also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

When you call `source` or `.` (the one is an alias to the other. [`source` cmd not POSIX - kind of *bashism*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot)), you load and execute a shell script **into the *current* shell process**. So you can

- read variables set in the sourced script,
- use functions defined within it.
- and even execute forks and/or subprocess if script do this.

When you call `sh`, you initiate a *fork* (sub-process or *child*) that runs a new session of `/bin/sh` (which is often a symbolic link to `bash`). In this case, environment variables set by the sub-script would be dropped when the sub-script terminate.

**Caution**: `sh` could be a symlink to *another* [shell](/questions/tagged/shell).

#### Practical sample

For example, if you want to change *current working directory* by a specific manner, you could not do

```
$ cat <<eof >myCd2Doc.sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/share/doc
eof

$ chmod +x myCd2Doc.sh
```

This won't do what you expect:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ pwd
/tmp
$ ~/myCd2Doc.sh
$ pwd
/tmp
```

because *current working dir* is part of environment and `myCd2Doc.sh` would run in a *subshell*.

But:

```
$ source ~/myCd2Doc.sh
$ pwd
/usr/share/doc
```

Same, for declaring a function:

```
$ cat >~/myCd2Doc.source <<eof
# Shell source file
myCd2Doc() {
    cd /usr/share/doc
}
eof

$ . ~/myCd2Doc.source
$ cd /tmp
$ pwd
/tmp
$ myCd2Doc
$ pwd
/usr/share/doc
```

Have a look at [*`mycd`* function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112493/1765658)!! (With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) completion based on *Associative Array*).

#### Execution level `$SHLVL`

```
$ cd /tmp
printf %b '\43\41/bin/bash\necho This is level \44SHLVL.\n' >qlvl.sh

$ bash qlvl.sh 
This is level 2.

$ source qlvl.sh 
This is level 1.
```

#### [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) (when a script run from itself)

```
$ cat <<"eoqlvl2" >qlvl2.sh 
#!/bin/bash

export startLevel recursionLimit=5
echo This is level $SHLVL started:${startLevel:=$SHLVL}.
(( SHLVL < recursionLimit )) && ./qlvl2.sh
eoqlvl2
$ chmod +x qlvl2.sh

$ ./qlvl2.sh 
This is level 2 started:2.
This is level 3 started:2.
This is level 4 started:2.
This is level 5 started:2.

$ source qlv2.sh 
This is level 1 started:1.
This is level 2 started:1.
This is level 3 started:1.
This is level 4 started:1.
This is level 5 started:1.
```

#### A little futher

```
$ sed '$a ps --sid $SID fw' qlvl.sh >qlvl3.sh
$ chmod +x qlvl3.sh 
$ export SID
$ read SID < <(ps ho sid $$)
$ echo $SID $$
8983 8983
```

( Current *PID* (`$$` == *process Id*) are same identifier than *SID* (*session ID*). It's not alway true.)

```
$ ./qlvl3.sh 
This is level 2.
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 8983 pts/10   Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
10266 pts/10   S+     0:00  \_ /bin/bash ./qlvl3.sh
10267 pts/10   R+     0:00      \_ ps --sid 8983 fw

$ . qlvl3.sh 
This is level 1.
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 8983 pts/10   Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
10428 pts/10   R+     0:00  \_ ps --sid 8983 fw
```

Dot `.` is an alias of `source`. So the only difference between two command are *`slash`* replaced by *`space`*.

#### And a *final* test:

```
$ printf %b '\43\41/bin/bash\necho Ending this.\nsle' \
    'ep 1;exit 0\n' >finalTest.sh

$ bash finalTest.sh 
Ending this.

$ source finalTest.sh
Ending this.
```

... You may notice a *different* behaviour between the two syntaxes. ;-)

Comment: Should also note that any environment variables that aren't exported won't be available to a script that is invoked under a new shell.

Comment: (The same goes for aliases and shell functions.)

Comment: @WillVousden: Alias seem not to be exportable at all, you could export variables and/or functions, but not aliases.

Comment: Yep, I don't think aliases can be exported.

Comment: @F.Hauri About the relationship between `source` and `.`, it's the other way around. `source` is a **bash-specific** alias for the standard [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) syntax `.`. Please consider modifying your answer to correct the phrasing accordingly.

Comment: @Atralb Considering POSIX, you'r right, but considering BASH, things are not as clear... Anyway, I've edited my answer...

Comment: There was a time when `sh` was commonly symlinked to `bash` on Linux systems, but this is no longer true. Even when it is, `bash` behaves differently when you invoke it through a symlink to `sh`.

Comment: @tripleee You're correct, anyway my answer is still correct and do already contain the warning: ***Caution: sh could be a symlink to another shell.***

Answer (score 18):

The main difference is that they are executed in a different process.

So if you `source` a file `foo` which does a `cd`, the sourcing shell (e.g. your interactive shell in the terminal) is affected (and its current directory will change)

If you execute `sh foo`  the `cd` does not affect the sourcing shell, only the freshly created `sh` process running `foo`

Read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

<sup>That difference is not specific to Linux; every Posix implementation would have it.</sup>

Comment: No, **do not** read the Advanced Bash (in fact they mean Bug) Scripting Guide

Comment: Why do you think the ABSG is wrong for newbies? It teaches a lot of useful things.... What alternative guide do you suggest?

Comment: It teaches the worse bash practices. Just look at the first examples, you'll understand how terrible it is: uppercase variable names, useless uses of cats, ...

Comment: Then suggest an alternative better tutorial document. I think it is good enough for newbies...

Comment: actually it explains very nice 
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#SOURCEREF

Comment: I don't know of any good tutorial for newbies (I actually don't know what you exactly put behind this word). There's the [bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) and [lhunath's guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). I haven't read the latter, but I know for sure that lhunath and greycat are among the most knowledgeable guys about bash. The question now is: _are these wonderful documents suited for "newbies"?_

Comment: One alternative is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and there are links to more at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, when you run `sh test.sh`, any changes that `test.sh` makes to your shell environment won't persist after the process has ended.

However, also note that any element of your environment that isn't exported (e.g., variables, aliases, and shell functions) won't be available to the code in `test.sh` when it is executed as a subprocess (i.e. with `sh test.sh`).

For example:

```sh
$ cat > test.sh
echo $foo
$ foo=bar
$ sh test.sh
$ . test.sh
bar
```

Example 2:

```
lap@my-ThinkPad:~$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /etc
lap@my-ThinkPad:~$ sh test.sh 
lap@my-ThinkPad:~$ pwd
/home/savoury
lap@my-ThinkPad:~$ source test.sh 
lap@my-ThinkPad:/etc$ pwd
/etc
lap@my-ThinkPad:/etc$
```

Answer (score 3):

**source** (or . ) - runs inside current shell and changes its attribute/environment.

**sh** do fork  and runs in a subshell and hence can't change attributes/environment.

**For example**

**My shell script is -**

```
elite12!rg6655:~/sh_pr [33]$ cat changeDir.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/elt/rg6655/sh_pr/justdir
pwd
echo $$
```

**My Current Shell -**

```
elite12!rg6655:~/sh_pr [32]$ echo $$
3272
```

Process id of my current shell is 3272

**Running with the *source* -**

```
elite12!rg6655:~/sh_pr [34]$ source changeDir.sh
/home/elt/rg6655/sh_pr/justdir
3272
elite12!rg6655:~/sh_pr/justdir
```

Observer two things - 
1) The process id (3272) is same as my shell, which confirms source executes in the current shell.
2) cd command worked and directory got changed to justdir.

**Running with *sh* -**

```
elite12!rg6655:~/sh_pr [31]$ sh changeDir.sh
/home/elt/rg6655/sh_pr/justdir
13673
elite12!rg6655:~/sh_pr
```

In this case, process id (13673) is different and directory remains the same which means it is running in a different process or subshell.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a program with sh command:

- your terminal will use sh or Bourne Shell to execute the program .
- a new process is created because Bash makes an exact copy of itself . this child process has the    same environment as its parent, only the process ID number is different. (this process called forking )
- you need to need to have execution permission to execute it ( since it is forking )

and when you use source command :

- you execute the program with your default interpreter
- you execute the process in your current terminal ( technically your *nix command interpreted )
- Since the program will be executed in current terminal you dont need to give it execution permission

Comment: You don't need execute permission to invoke by passing it as an argument to `sh` (e.g. `sh test.sh`).  You only need it if you want to invoke it directly (e.g. `./test.sh`).