# How to export a library path from a child shell script and use the path in the parent shell?

Tags: linux, shell, export

I have the following files

1. build.sh

   ```
   source exportpath.sh
   ```
2. exportpath.sh

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
   ```

But,when I am executing this build.sh and then running the `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` command I am not able to get the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value. How to set this value to the `current shell`.

I found that we have to `source` it in the current shell. But I want it done by a shell script.

When I am using `source exportpath.sh` in current shell, then my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is working but I want this should be done by a shell script.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? What is the overall goal??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export a variable to the environment from a bash script without sourcing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-it)

Answer (score 2):

There is no magical way to have an environment variable set in the child shell be propagated to the parent shell. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13786515/841108)

You could implement some convention, for instance by having `exportpath.sh` taking a filename, that `build.sh` would later `source` (or use `eval`).

You may want to have your own shell `function` to wrap both.

But **you should** usually **not do such weird tricks**. For example, you could wrap some of your programs into a shell script setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (*mozilla* or `firefox` is often doing such things).

Answer (score -4):

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Note the Use of "$" to reference the variable value.

Comment: But the child shell and the parent shell won't magically share changed (in the child) environment variables.

Comment: Thanks TheRuss ,this is the typo error I have made.I need,a simple solution to my problem if it there.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch : exactly,this is the problem I am facing,can you have any solution.