# Can I export a variable to the environment from a Bash script without sourcing it?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, environment-variables

Suppose that I have this script:

**export.bash**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
export VAR="HELLO, VARIABLE"
```

When I execute the script and try to access to the `$VAR`, I don't get any value!

```
echo $VAR
```

Is there a way to access the `$VAR` by just executing `export.bash` without sourcing it?

Comment: You could try using an alias instead of a script to define your variable.

Comment: The script that I'm working on, is some kind of a java virtual manager , I do some computation then I should export a $JAVA_HOME to the env, and append it to PATH.

Comment: Well, you could write the info to a file and then read it back in, but sourcing seems much easier.

Comment: child processes cannot alter their parent's environment. The parent has to choose to alter itself (either with `source` or `eval` or ...)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman , I end up with by wrapping the commands in a function and source it from .bash_profile .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global environment variables in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: To read more on source, `man source` won't work because `source` is built into bash, you need to run `help source`

Comment: @peter - Wow. I can't believe I've been using `bash` for over a decade and this is the first time I've ever heard of `help`.

Comment: @ArtWarfare help also works as a reference for common shell constructs such as if, for...etc.

Comment: to dump the full environment of a subshell, use `declare -p` for variables and `declare -pf` for functions, see also [How to list all variables names and their current values?](https://askubuntu.com/a/277969/877276)

Answer (score 504, accepted):

> Is there any way to access to the `$VAR` by just executing `export.bash` without sourcing it ?

Quick answer: No.

But there are several possible workarounds.

The most obvious one, which you've already mentioned, is to use `source` or `.` to execute the script in the context of the calling shell:

```
$ cat set-vars1.sh 
export FOO=BAR
$ . set-vars1.sh 
$ echo $FOO
BAR
```

Another way is to have the script, rather than setting an environment variable, print commands that will set the environment variable:

```
$ cat set-vars2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo export FOO=BAR
$ eval "$(./set-vars2.sh)"
$ echo "$FOO"
BAR
```

A third approach is to have a script that sets your environment variable(s) internally and then invokes a specified command with that environment:

```
$ cat set-vars3.sh
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=BAR
exec "$@"
$ ./set-vars3.sh printenv | grep FOO
FOO=BAR
```

This last approach can be quite useful, though it's inconvenient for interactive use since it doesn't give you the settings in your current shell (with all the other settings and history you've built up).

Comment: Could you please explain the third approach regarding `exec "$@"` and `printenv` thing?
Also, how can 2nd and 3rd approach be used in the case where the script takes some arguments?

Comment: I've a script takes some arguments. `sudo . dd.sh $source $pathToUsb` command not found or `eval "$(sudo dd.sh $source $pathToUsb)"` sh: 1: eval: File: not found
sh: 2: eval: File: not found or  if trying `./dd.sh $source $pathToUsb printenv | grep line` can't exec "@" . Any ideas ?

Comment: The `.` command is built into the shell, so it's not visible to `sudo`. Your second command will try to `eval` the *output* of the `sudo dd.sh ...` command, and I have no idea what that output looks like. Does `dd.sh` print commands that can be evaluated by the shell?

Comment: Could you please clarify this : "doesn't give you the settings in your current shell "?

Comment: @Erwann In the example I used, the command executed is `printenv`, which is affected only by environment variables. But if you invoke an interactive shell instead of `printenv`, then you have a new shell process, which doesn't inherit your current shell's history (except perhaps via `$HISTFILE`), non-exported variables, background jobs, etc.

Comment: @DarshanL - `"$@"` is an array-like construct of positional arguments (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, etc.) that you'd pass to a script. For 2nd approach, do something like `eval "$(./set-vars2.sh arg1 arg2)"`. For 3rd, you could account for `printenv` being your final argument, and do `for i; do :; done; exec "$i"` instead of `exec "$@"`.

Answer (score 89):

In order to export out the VAR variable first, the most logical and seemly working way is to source the variable:

```
. ./export.bash
```

or

```
source ./export.bash
```

Now when echoing from the main shell, it works:

```
echo $VAR
HELLO, VARIABLE
```

We will now reset VAR:

```
export VAR=""
echo $VAR
```

Now we will execute a script to source the variable then unset it:

```
./test-export.sh
HELLO, VARIABLE
--
.
```

The code: file *test-export.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
# Source env variable
source ./export.bash

# echo out the variable in test script
echo $VAR

# unset the variable
unset VAR
# echo a few dotted lines
echo "---"
# now return VAR which is blank
echo $VAR
```

Here is one way:

*Please note*: The exports are limited to the script that execute the exports in your main console - so as far as a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job I would add it like the console like below... for the command part still questionable: here is how you would run in from your shell:

On your command prompt (so long as the export.bash *file* has multiple echo values)

```
IFS=$'\n'; for entries in $(./export.bash); do  export $entries;  done; ./v1.sh
HELLO THERE
HI THERE
```

#### File cat v1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $VAR
echo $VAR1
```

Now so long as this is for your usage - you could make the variables available for your scripts at any time by doing a Bash alias like this:

```
myvars ./v1.sh
HELLO THERE
HI THERE

echo $VAR

.
```

Add this to your *[.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*:

```
function myvars() {
    IFS=$'\n';
    for entries in $(./export.bash); do  export $entries;  done;

    "$@";

    for entries in $(./export.bash); do variable=$(echo $entries|awk -F"=" '{print $1}'); unset $variable;
    done
}
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) your *.bashrc* file and you can do like the above any time...

Anyhow back to the rest of it...

This has made it available globally then executed the script...

Simply echo it out and run export on the echo!

#### File *export.bash*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "VAR=HELLO THERE"
```

Now within script or your console run:

```
export "$(./export.bash)"
```

Try:

```
echo $VAR
HELLO THERE
```

Multiple values so long as you know what you are expecting in another script using the above method:

#### File *export.bash*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "VAR=HELLO THERE"
echo "VAR1=HI THERE"
```

#### File *test-export.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
for entries in $(./export.bash); do
    export $entries
done

echo "round 1"
echo $VAR
echo $VAR1

for entries in $(./export.bash); do
    variable=$(echo $entries|awk -F"=" '{print $1}');
    unset $variable
done

echo "round 2"
echo $VAR
echo $VAR1
```

Now the results

```
./test-export.sh
round 1
HELLO THERE
HI THERE
round 2


.
```

And the final final update to auto assign, read the VARIABLES:

```
./test-export.sh
Round 0 - Export out then find variable name -
Set current variable to the variable exported then echo its value
$VAR has value of HELLO THERE
$VAR1 has value of HI THERE
round 1 - we know what was exported and we will echo out known variables
HELLO THERE
HI THERE
Round 2 - We will just return the variable names and unset them
round 3 - Now we get nothing back
```

The script:

#### File *test-export.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
echo "Round 0 - Export out then find variable name - "
echo "Set current variable to the variable exported then echo its value"
for entries in $(./export.bash); do
    variable=$(echo $entries|awk -F"=" '{print $1}');
    export $entries
    eval current_variable=\$$variable
    echo "\$$variable has value of $current_variable"
done


echo "round 1 - we know what was exported and we will echo out known variables"
echo $VAR
echo $VAR1

echo "Round 2 - We will just return the variable names and unset them "
for entries in $(./export.bash); do
    variable=$(echo $entries|awk -F"=" '{print $1}');
    unset $variable
done

echo "round 3 - Now we get nothing back"
echo $VAR
echo $VAR1
```

Comment: I want to export VAR by executing the file, not by sourcing it.

Comment: @vahid you should explain what your script is doing.

Comment: why not unset the variable after sourcing ? it be a lot easier than the pain your trying to cause yourself  will update the test-export script

Comment: I gave an alternative way of doing it Tarrsalah

Comment: ok final updates - issues with the suggested method and work arounds the bashrc alias idea would probably be a great way forth

Comment: I am not sure why the author says he does not want to source the script. That just seems like this is exactly the command to achieve what he wants.

Comment: You seem to have the knowledge that I need, but am still trying to grasp. If you could take a look at this question here and see if you know an answer I'd be very appreciative: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209780/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application-which-uniquely-modifies.

Answer (score 48):

Execute

```
set -o allexport
```

Any variables you source from a file after this will be exported in your shell.

```
source conf-file
```

When you're done execute. This will disable allexport mode.

```
set +o allexport
```

Comment: The entire point of the question is "How to export without source". This answer uses source.

Comment: @ekkis Yeah it doesn't exactly answer the question, but whenever I googled how to export variables from a file this thread came up. So I kind of just put it there for myself.

Comment: I upvoted this because the original problem statement lead me to understand that this was my fundamental solution. There's official docs on allexport here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Answer (score 22):

I found an interesting and neat way to export environment variables from a file:

In file *env.vars*:

```
foo=test
```

Test script:

```
eval `cat env.vars`
echo $foo         # => test
sh -c 'echo $foo' # =>

export eval `cat env.vars`
echo $foo         # => test
sh -c 'echo $foo' # => test

# a better one. "--" stops processing options,
# key=value list given as parameters
export -- `cat env.vars`
echo $foo         # => test
sh -c 'echo $foo' # => test
```

Answer (score 13):

Another workaround that, depends on the case, it could be useful: creating another bash script that inherits the exported variable. It is a particular case of [Keith Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i/16619261#16619261), will all of those drawbacks.

**File export.bash:**

```
# !/bin/bash
export VAR="HELLO, VARIABLE"
bash
```

Now:

```
./export.bash
echo $VAR
```

Comment: Are you sure that what you wrote works!? I believe that you have to execute the line command: `. ./export.bash`

Comment: @Sir Jo Black, yes, sure. The last line of the export.bash file invoke `bash` as child of the current shell. And since `VAR` was exported before, that invocation will include the variable. Of course, if you type `exit` the `VAR` will go out. Have you checked?

Comment: Ok! I've not seen that invocation ... :p

Comment: This will create a new bash shell, the old one will keep running. If you wanted to exit, you must exit twice, from the new one and then from the old one, that still do not have the exported environment variables.

Comment: @fflores As it says, depends on the case, it could be useful. In other cases is not, for instance, because creating the second interactive bash.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, but for me I did the following

The script:

myExport

```
#! \bin\bash
export $1
```

An alias in my [.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example):

```
alias myExport='source myExport'
```

Still you [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) it, but maybe in this way it is more useable and it is interesting for someone else.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

## **Export environment variables using script file**

***Problem:***
When you run a script, it executes in a child shell and returns back to the parent shell after execution. Exporting variables only works down the child shells, you can't export a child shell's variable back to the parent shell.

***Solution:***
From your script file invoke a child shell along with variables that you want to export, this will create a new child shell with your variables exported.

**script.sh** ->

```
bash -c 'export VAR=variable; exec bash'
```

: : CIPH3R

[image: Export Variables using script]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can add a function in *~/.zshrc* or *~/.bashrc*.

```
# set my env
[ -s ~/.env ] && export MYENV=`cat ~/.env`
function myenv() { [[ -s ~/.env ]] && echo $argv > ~/.env && export MYENV=$argv }
```

Because of the use of a variable outside, you can avoid the use of a script file.

Answer (score 2):

simple naive approach that works:

script 1:

`echo "something" > /tmp/myvar`

script 2:

`myvar=$(cat /tmp/myvar)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a variable for the calling shell there is a robust approach using c unix sockets.
The result will be tested like this:

```
$ ./a.out &
[1] 5363
$ ./b.out 123;a=`./b.out`;echo ${a}
123
[1]+  Done                    ./a.out
```

See [a.c](https://github.com/colin-i/test/blob/main/stats/a.c), [b.c](https://github.com/colin-i/test/blob/main/stats/b.c), and [a.h](https://github.com/colin-i/test/blob/main/stats/a.h) from my github.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done, but I found a workaround using `alias`. It will only work when you place your script in your scripts directory. Otherwise your alias will have an invalid name.

The only point to the workaround is to be able to have a function inside a file with the same name and not have to bother sourcing it before using it. Add the following code to file `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias myFunction='unalias myFunction && . myFunction && myFunction "$@"'
```

You can now call `myFunction` without [sourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) it first.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround is somehow hinted to elsewhere, but maybe not that clearly:

In your script, after setting the variable, **start a new shell**, rather than return.

My use cases is that I have a number of terminals open and in some of them I want some values for some variables, while in others I want other values.

As using `source` may be harder to remember, a small advantage of this approach is when it takes a while to realize that you forgot to use `source`, and you have to start from scratch.

(For me it makes more sense to use `source script`, as the missing variables are noticed immediately.)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem calling ssh-agent -s in a script called by option -e in rsync.

In the script eval $(ssh-agent -s) don't preserve the environment variables for the next call.

rsync -e 'source ssh-check-agent.sh -p 8022' does not work, so I made a workaround. In the script I saved the variables in a temporal file after call ssh-agent like:

```
echo "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK;" > /tmp/ssh-check-agent.vars
echo "export SSH_AGENT_PID=$SSH_AGENT_PID;" >> /tmp/ssh-check-agent.vars
```

and after in the script that calls rsync (backup.sh) I call:

```
source /tmp/ssh-check-agent.vars
```

The problem is that script that calls rsync must be called by source (source backup.sh).

I know that is not the question (I use two times source), but I put here if someone has similar problem with rsync.