# Chromedriver works manually but fails when ran from Jenkins Slave

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Jenkins slave node setup with LinuxMint. So we can do some browser testing on a Linux box in Chrome and Firefox.

I have the latest Chromedriver installed where the test can run it and when I go into `/var/jenkins/workspace/<project name>/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework` manually and do my `run npm <test name>` the tests launch the chromedriver and run successfully.

When I go into Jenkins and run my test chromedriver is failing with the following and I am not sure where to go with this.:

> Using ChromeDriver directly...
>   [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   /var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108
>     var template = new Error(this.message);
>                    ^
>   UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 3.19.0-32-generic x86_64)
>       at new bot.Error (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
>       at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:109:9)
>       at /var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:160:24
>       at promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1857:20)
>       at goog.defineClass.notify (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2448:25)
>       at promise.Promise.notify_ (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:564:12)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:553:15)
>       at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:130:15)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>   From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
>       at new Driver (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
>       at DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:16)
>       at Runner.createBrowser (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:182:37)
>       at /var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:263:21
>       at _fulfilled (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
>       at /var/jenkins/workspace/QA-E2E-Linux/TestAutomation/SeleniumFramework/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
>   [launcher] Process exited with error code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was connecting to the slaves from the Jenkins master via SSH. This wasn't ever going to launch a browser session. I switched over to the Java Web Start option, and it launched the browser just fine.

Answer (score 2):

**First Solution:**

Have you java 8 installed? If yes, uninstall it and install java 7.

**Second Solution:**

Downgrade protractor to v1.8.0

~

*More informations:* https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1905

@edit

I found a similar topic as your, the same error in jenkins - linux:

```
In you jenkins settings add a global property

key : DISPLAY
value:0:0

On your server start Xvfb in the background:

Xvfb :0 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

link: [unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri)

Comment: Neither solution works. I can still run the tests manually on the Jenkins slave, I cannot run them from Jenkins.

Comment: I found more informations about your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out what the problem was. I was connecting to the slaves from Jenkins via SSH. Once I changed to the Java Web Start, it worked just fine and the browser launched.