# Travis: Unable to find chromedriver

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, cucumber, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate travis to my cucumber tests using watir. However, Now, I seem to be stuck in the last problem with chromedriver. I get the error

```
Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from    http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
```

(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

I fixed this thing in my local windows machine by adding `chromedriver` in `lib` folder of `ruby` and adding path to `system32, webem`

I am not sure on how to do about this in `Travis`. Can someone help me?

My .travis.yml file looks like this

```
sudo: required
language: ruby
cache: bundler

rvm: 2.2

 before_script:
    - bundle install
    - gem install watir
    - gem install colorize
    - gem install rspec
    - gem install cucumber
script: bundle exec cucumber

branches:
only:
- master

notifications:
email:
- iamsmj@gmail.com
```

I have added the below code to the existing .yml

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - chromium-browser
          - chromium-chromedriver

rvm: 2.2

```
before_script:
    - bundle install
    - gem install watir
    - gem install colorize
    - gem install rspec
    - gem install cucumber
    - wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip
      - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
      - sudo chmod u+x chromedriver
      - sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/
      - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
      - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
      - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
      - sleep 3
      - ./travis_before_install
```

The error i get now is

```
    --2017-02-13 18:04:46--  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip
    Resolving chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)... 64.233.191.128, 2607:f8b0:4001:c0c::80
    Connecting to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)|64.233.191.128|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 2692616 (2.6M) [application/zip]
    Saving to: `chromedriver_linux64.zip'
     0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s                100%[======================================>] 2,692,616   --.-K/s   in 0.009s  



    wget: unable to resolve host address `.'
    FINISHED --2017-02-13 18:04:48--
    Total wall clock time: 1.5s
    Downloaded: 1 files, 2.6M in 0.009s (281 MB/s)
    The command "wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip - sudo chmod u+x chromedriver - sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/ - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser - "export DISPLAY=:99.0" - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start" - sleep 3 - ./travis_before_install" failed and exited with 4 during .
    Your build has been stopped.


Also, Could someone please let me know, why travis wouldnt run this?

`The command "bundle exec cucumber" exited with 2.`


UPDATE: I updated the file fixing the indentation in the `before_script` . The latest error i get is 

    0.08s$ unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
   Archive:  chromedriver_linux64.zip
  inflating: chromedriver            
   before_script.10
   0.01s$ sudo chmod u+x chromedriver
   before_script.11
   0.01s$ sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/
   before_script.12
   0.00s$ export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
   before_script.13
   0.00s$ export DISPLAY=:99.0
   before_script.14
   0.01s$ sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
   Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
   before_script.15
   3.01s$ sleep 3
   2.55s$ bundle exec cucumber
   end of file reached (EOFError)
   The command "bundle exec cucumber" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1. 


     **Update:** I tried fixing up the identation errors in the script as. The new error i get is 

     0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s                  100%[======================================>] 2,692,616   --.-K/s   in 0.01s   
   2017-02-14 11:00:45 (173 MB/s) - ‘chromedriver_linux64.zip’ saved    [2692616/2692616]
    before_script.9
   0.08s$ unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
   Archive:  chromedriver_linux64.zip
   inflating: chromedriver            
    before_script.10
   0.01s$ sudo chmod u+x chromedriver
   before_script.11
   0.01s$ sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/
   before_script.12
   0.00s$ export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
   before_script.13
   0.00s$ export DISPLAY=:99.0
   before_script.14
   0.01s$ sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
   Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
   before_script.15
   3.01s$ sleep 3
   2.55s$ bundle exec cucumber
   **end of file reached (EOFError)**
   The command "bundle exec cucumber" exited with 2.
    Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: Did you try setting is explicitly in your script?

`Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.executable_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'`

Comment: @Raphael Nope! Didnt! Can you tell me where do I have to mention this code? Is it in `before_script`?

Comment: @Raphael : This is the raw log

https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/201230860/log.txt?deansi=true

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in the `before_script` stage and run a build again?

Comment: Okay! @joepd : There is some progress now. I have updated my question. Please take a look

Comment: This is the raw log, https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/201469568/log.txt?deansi=true

Comment: Somehow cucumber cannot read the files it needs to read. I see some indentation errors over there as well. Do the tests run on your local machine? What if you make a clone of your repository to a new, temporary directory?

Comment: @joepd : Yes the tests run in the local machine. I just erased the old directory and made a new one, and it runs.

Comment: By saying cucumber files, what do u mean? Are u talking about the `feature` file?

Comment: I tried pushing a feature file to see if travis wud run it. And Now i get this error. It looks like, the `chromedriver` access issue?

https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/201526250/log.txt?deansi=true

Comment: Finally, I could pass the chromedriver error, but now I think, my tests arent launching there . PFB the log file 

https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/201587885/log.txt?deansi=true

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Was able to get the travis run my cucumber tests.

Changes I did

1. Provided sudo for permission change that used to displayed `Not permitted`
2. Downgraded Chromedriver version from `2.7` to `2.27`

These fixed it

The current `.travis.yml` file looks like this

```
sudo: required
language: ruby

dist: trusty

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
       - google-chrome
    packages:
    - google-chrome-stable


 script: bundle exec cucumber


 before_script:
    - bundle install
    - gem install watir
    - gem install colorize
    - gem install rspec
    - gem install cucumber
    - gem install rake
    - gem install chromium
    - wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
    - sudo apt-get install libnss3
    - sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
    - sudo cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin/.
    - sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
    - export DISPLAY=:99.0
    - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
    - sleep 3


branches:
 only:
  - master

notifications:
 email:
- iamsmj@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution for myself, since I encountered the same error, but it didn't work out. After combining [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-the-Chrome-addon-in-the-headless-mode) and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri) answer I ended up with this setup, which works:

```
dist: trusty

language: ruby

sudo: required

before_install:
  - gem install bundler
  - "rm ${BUNDLE_GEMFILE}.lock"
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &

cache: bundler

rvm:
 - 2.4.0

env:
 - DB=pgsql

services:
 - postgresql

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: app_test

addons:
  chrome: stable

# uncomment and edit the following line if your project needs to run something other than `rake`:
# script: 
# - bundle exec rspec spec

before_script:
 - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
 - psql -c 'create database app_test;' -U postgres
 - bundle update
 - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
 - export DISPLAY=:99.0
 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
 - sleep 3

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: "api_ley"
  app: awesome-development-app

notifications:
  slack: app:key
```

Important steps are:
`google-chrome-stable` in `before_install`, `addons` - `chrome` - `stable` and `DISPLAY` value.

Maybe it helps someone.