# chromedriver in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: behat

I install chromedriver and selenium with this way https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5 
but i have this error when I lunched test behat with brwoser chromium not lunched.

behat.yml:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            bundle: MedBundle
            contexts:
                - test\MedBundle\Behat\Context\FeatureContext
                - test\MedBundle\Behat\Context\AjouterContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://localhost/test/web/app_dev.php
            goutte: ~
            browser_name: 'chrome'
            javascript_session: selenium2
            selenium2:
                wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
```

this is problem :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Be3.png)

Comment: You need to try different combinations of `selenium server standalone` and `chromedriver` and see what works, since Chrome can update you might need to update one of them or both. Start with the latest (selenium `3.3.1` and chromedriver `2.29`) and after that vary one of them or both, also make sure selenium starts successfully before staring to run any test.

Comment: with selenium 3.3.1 and chromedriver 2.29,when I lunch test i have this problems: in terminal lunch server selenium i have this problem: 
http://imgur.com/a/Wxoyw and in terminal lunchcommande test behat i have this problem :http://imgur.com/a/5eJZd

Comment: Please see this, it may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri

Comment: @dev_2017 Have you started your selenium-server-standalone in your terminal before running the tests? I mean this: [Running selenium server standalone and chromedriver](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/js7k/running-selenium-server-standalone-and-cromedriver)

Comment: Look at this too: [Running behat2 tests with different browsers](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6djs/running-behat2-tests-with-different-browsers)