# Running Selenium Scripts as Jenkins Job

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Need your expertise with below problem.

I have a linux centos 7 machine , has a GUI.
I can run selenium scripts on that machine using the 64 bit chromedriver.

The issue comes when am trying to run those scripts as a Jenkins job on that machine.
It gives  the following error:

> unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.33.506092
>   (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux
>   3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.12 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time:’' System
>   info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri

Comment: Thanks @DurdenP. Yes I did have a look at it, the thing is the Xvfb plugin is used when u do not have a display, but the machine I am using is having a display(it’s actually a vmware machine with a GUI)