# Xvfb Selenium headless Chrome on Linux in Python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run chrome headless with selenium in Python.
I tried `xvfb-run -a python3 message.py`
And i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "message.py", line 388, in <module>
    initialize()
  File "message.py", line 54, in initialize
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506178 (69ae10f91723897591ef1a3b465aa5d35011eb5e),platform=Linux 3.13.0-96-generic x86)
```

And initialize():

```
   chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
   chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
   chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
   chrome_options.add_argument("--log-path=chrome.log")
   chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
   chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=\\")
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
   driver.get('http://google.com')
```

I'm using Python 3.5 and chromedriver 2.33.506178 for Linux32 (Ubuntu as Server without Desktop)
I tested the same code on my other pc with linux mint, all works fine.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri)

Comment: I don't want to use Jenkins, whether this isn't necessary. So this post is not helpful, i think.

Comment: It's not about jenkins. It's about using chrome in headless mode using xvfb. You need to set the display amount to either zero or something. Read through the post.

Comment: At least I already tried to set the display value 0:0 .
But i still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my actual rights of writing/reading/executing I found my mistake. chromedriver weren't able to load while trying to execute with root rights.
After I changed chromedrivers permission all works fine now.