# Jenkins - ERROR Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Ubuntu - Jenkins and GIT in Ubuntu, 
Java project using selenium

Trying to run GIT project in Jenkins(Jenkins with Agent node).

Error in Jenkins

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-39-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 254 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'WebTest-VM', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-39-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Note: Same java + Selenium project able to open chrome browser in local machine

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/webtest/Downloads/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: I found a solution for above issue my answer may help others change chrome driver path to public static String chromeDriverPath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"; System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath); WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); Fallowed below tutorial solved my all problems.    http://stgconsulting.com/running-automated-selenium-tests-from-jenkins-on-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `JenkinsFile` to your project and commit to git

[image]

Your `JenkinsFile` could have following syntax:

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'maven_3_5_0' 
    }
    stages {

         stage('Checkout Code from Git') {
               steps {
        git 'https://github.com/xxxxxxx/your-project.git'
    }}

    stage('compile stage') {
             steps {
                bat "mvn clean compile"
        }
    }

         stage('testing stage') {
             steps {
                bat "mvn test"
        }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Dear kushal Jenkinsfile is text file ?

Comment: im getting chrome failure to open browser can you please recheck my above post

Comment: Please try and keep `chromedriver.exe` in your project itself under resources or so. Then insted of path like this `/home/webtest/Downloads/chromedriver` use relative path to chromedriver something like `src/test/res/chromedriver.exe`

Comment: IM using Ubuntu OS - within local system codes are working fine and when i'm trying to run in Jenkins(Jenkins in server) getting above issue.

Comment: try solutions mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri

Comment: I found a solution for above issue my answer may help others change chrome driver path to                                                                                             
 public static String chromeDriverPath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"; System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();                                                                         Fallowed below tutorial solved my all problems. http://stgconsulting.com/running-automated-selenium-tests-from-jenkins-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2012, just download the chromedriver suitable for your Chrome version.
Put that driver in common place for all users. In Drive `C:\Tools\Chromedriver` for example. Then in your Jenkins instance, just update the env variables with the path to that driver.