# Export in BASH script and source command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i), simply placing the `export` command in a `bash` script does not affect an environment variable unless the `source` command is used.  However, after installing Anaconda for Python, I noticed the installer added the following line in the shell script `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/host/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

Running `printenv` reveals this statement did indeed seem to have the desired effect.  My questions are, how does the export statement in the script effect the environment variables without the `source` command, and why is the `source` command usually needed to have this effect?  I.e., why doesn't the script just perform the `export` statement without the `source` command/

Comment: `.bashrc` is implicitly sourced, not executed, when a non-login interactive shell starts.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b