# Linux script variable passing to next cronjob schedule

Tags: linux

I wanted to know if there is possibility in Linux shell scripting where variable stored in first script execution ( cron job) can be passed to next cron job schedule

For example : If my script store some value in variable X in first execution , then this value should be passed to script execution in next cron job schedule and so on..

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I export a variable to the environment from a bash script without sourcing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i)

Comment: also https://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working