# Sending a value to expect command doesn't apply the value

Tags: bash, expect

I wrote a bash script to download a specific java binary tar ball, untar it, and then configure the java version
Since the java install tool requires manual interaction I'm using "expect" to "send" the answer to the command.
I put the java binaries into "/opt"

```
curl -o /opt/jdk-8u201.tar.gz https://hostname
tar -zxvf /opt/jdk-8u201.tar.gz -C /opt
```

```
#!/bin/bash

yum -y install expect
EXPECT=$(which expect)
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-8u201
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ${JAVA_HOME%/}/bin/java 2000
${EXPECT} <<EOD
spawn update-alternatives --config java
expect "Enter to keep the current selection\[\+\], or type selection number:"
send 3
EOD
```

When I perform the installation manually and enter:
`echo $JAVA_PATH`
it prints the information.
If I do it in a shell script, it does not update the path.

Is there something I don't see? Thank you

Cheers,
Roland

Comment: How do you run the script? Can you print JAVA_PATH inside the script after updating and post the output of the script?

Comment: Your script runs in a sub shell. A sub shell can only change the values of variables within itself and other shells it creates (for exported variables), it can't affect the calling shell unless invoked as `. script` or via `source` instead of just `script`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16618071/1745001

Comment: @BlackPearl thank you. While using a statement ```echo $JAVA_HOME``` I get the following error message: ```invalid command name "echo" while executing "echo /opt/jdk-8u201```, So, it seems that inside the expect call it knows what the ```$JAVA_PATH``` variable is but not afterwards, like what @Ed Morton refers to.

Comment: Yes. I overlooked it.  You probably have to use `source`.

Comment: do you use source within the expect block and what would you actually sourve, the java version?

Comment: On another side not, could I also export the currently installed java version as in 
``` 
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
```
Where the current jdk binaries are under
```
/usr/lib/jvm
```

Comment: There are multiple java versions listed there and a bit difficult which one to export
```
java -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk
java-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk.1.8.0
java-1.8.0_openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk.1.8.0_openjdk
java-1.8.0_openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.e7_2.x86_64
java-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk.1.8.0_openjdk
jre
jre-1.8.0 ->  /etc/alternatives/jre-1.8.0
jre-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre-1.8.0_openjdk
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.e7_2.x86_64
jre-opejdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre-openjdk
```

Comment: So, would I export the current java version as in
```
export JAVA_HOME=java-1.8.0_openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.e7_2.x86_64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: ahh, here is a very simple solution to the initial question, doesn't even require an expect block.   ```echo 2 | alternatives --config java```