# I am trying to run a file from bash on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash

I am new on Ubuntu and Linux, shell scripting etc. I have prepared a small script in order to set some enviromental variables, in order to make my life faster and work more efficient with a program. While it is easy to open the terminal and set the that manually.

```
if [ -f /home/lefteris/uems/etc/EMS.profile ]; then
  . /home/lefteris/uems/etc/EMS.profile
fi
```

When I put it on a script, which I call variables.sh it is not working. File it is like that.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /home/lefteris/uems/etc/EMS.profile ]; then
  . /home/lefteris/uems/etc/EMS.profile
fi
```

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where do you need the script for? for what purpose?

Comment: Also what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set environment variables just by running the shell script. You have to source it or use *dot space script* method.

You have used a correct method above, but when putting it in a script file and executing doesn't set the variables as you again trying to set variables by running the script.

You can try `. variables.sh` or `source variables.sh`

Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i) for more details.