# How to set enviroment variable from shell script

Tags: shell, environment-variables

script file `set_env`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=some_path/openssl/lib/
```

I run it from the terminal: `./set_env`

but variable is not established:

```sh
printenv | grep "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

prints nothing.

So it should be?

Comment: You can't. A child process cannot affect the environment of its parent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I export a variable to the environment from a bash script without sourcing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child process cannot change the environment of the parent.

The only way to do this is to have the parent environment *source* the script.
It's all in how your "run" it.

```
./set_env   # won't work creates a child process that evaporates
. ./set_env # reads the script in the *CURRENT* environment, loads the vars
```