# How to import a variable form bash script which will be avaialble globally?

Tags: bash, shell

I have bash1.sh file:

```
abc=100
export abc
```

Other file bash2.sh:

`source bash1.sh`

when I run `./bash2.sh` and try to `echo $abc`  or `export -p`  , it doesn't display abc. But If I manually do `source ./bash1.sh` , it will print abc value. How to source ./bash1.sh from bash2.sh so abc will be global var?

Comment: It should work; there is probably something else going on. Are you running the script in the directory where both files exist? Do you get any sort of error message?

Comment: Or do you mean you run `bash2.sh` and then try to `echo` this variable after it finishes? That won't work, for the same reason you have to `source` from inside the script for the variable to be available in the parent script.

Comment: Directory is same for both files. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i) tried 3rd approach of first ans, not working for me.  file prat1.sh : ```echo export FOO1=BAR``` and file prat2.sh: ```eval "$(./prat.sh)"```. Ran prat2.sh and ```$echo $FOO1```(cmd), nothing display. @tripleee

Comment: It's still not clear if you expect the variable to persist after `prat2.sh` finishes. If so, that can't be done.

Comment: Precisely, I want process ID to be fetch from bash script and want to import in other file. I got PID in my bash script, exported it, when other file finds that variable value NULL. So how do i make that variable persist.  Like "source <bashfile>" keeps manually. @tripleee

Comment: The duplicate really does explain this, and so do a number of similar questions. A process cannot change its parent's environment without cooperation from the parent.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. @tripleee