# How to set environment variable so that CMakelists.txt from NDK can access?

Tags: android, macos, cmake, android-ndk, environment-variables

I need to set an environment variable when building an Android app using NDK so that all the CMakeLists.txt files in my NDK project can access that value. Most likely I only need to set that value for this particular app. Any straightforward to do that?

Things I've tried:

I've tried to use a bash script to set the env, and run the script before `preBuild` during gradle build. I think the script was executed, however, the env var is not set, at least not readable from CMakeLists.txt files. Here's the code in `app/build.gradle`:

```
task runBuildScript(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "bash", "-c", './set-env.sh'

}

project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn(runBuildScript)
}
```

This is pretty much all the script does:

```
DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
export SDK_BASE=$( cd "$( dirname "$DIR" )/../../" > /dev/null && pwd )
```

This is how I plan to use that env var in my CMakeLists.txt files:

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$ENV{SDK_BASE}/build-tools/cmake")
include(sdk_module) # this line will only work if the above command can find the module from the correct location
```

FYI, I'm using Android Studio on Mac to build this app, if that matters.

Comment: A shell script (`set-env.sh` in your case) cannot modify environment of the **outer shell**. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to set an environment variable when building an Android app using NDK so that all the CMakeLists.txt files in my NDK project can access that value.

So, you have Gradle invoking CMake?

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#variables)

> If building with Gradle, add arguments to `android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.arguments` as described in the ExternalNativeBuild docs. If building from the command line, pass arguments to CMake with `-D`.

The [`ExternalNativeBuild` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/variant/ExternalNativeBuild) mention `arguments`, but there isn't a lot of detail.

Still, you can see examples of `externalNativeBuild.cmake.arguments` in Gradle in the NDK samples, such as [here](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/main/hello-libs/app/build.gradle):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version '3.18.1'
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly when passing args directly from gradle to cmake, do you know how to make it work when passing args indirectly as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74247696/9142279)?

Comment: No idea. Literally everything I knew on this subject I learned from the linked documentation and have since forgotten.