# Exports inside subprocess.check_output() do not take effect for other commands inside same subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
command="./foo/s.sh && echo $VAR_T"
subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

s.sh does `export VAR_T='foo'` but for some reason its not visible to the echo command right after.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/can-i-export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-i

Comment: Environment variables flow solely from parent to child process, and never the other way.  `./foo/s.sh` is run in a subshell, after which its variables vanish completely.  I think you'd need to do `source foo/s.sh` instead, so that it's setting variables in the same shell that's going to execute the `echo`.

Comment: Ughhhhhhhhh I hate bash so much, can't source it for some reason, it fails

Comment: Hmmm the source only seems to fail inside the subprocess, in the regular shell (where I call the script from it works), it fails with "not a valid identifier" in one of the lines

Comment: Do I need to set a version of bash or something through python?

Comment: I think shell=True uses your default shell, which might be ash or dash or something else... you could do `subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', command])` to force it to use bash

Answer (score 0):

calling as a subproccess can't set the enviorment of the parent, so you need to source the script, which also means you need to define your shell. The easiest way that I know of to accomplish these would be:

```python
command="source ./foo/s.sh && echo $VAR_T"
subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c',command])
```