# Export Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have one script named a.sh from where I'm calling b.sh and passing some parameters from a.sh to b.sh . After b.sh is completed I'm exporting some variables from b.sh and I want to echo it from a.sh . I'm using export command in b.sh but I when I'm doing an echo command It is not showing anything in a.sh .

```
#b.sh
x=1
#some function is there
export $x

#a.sh
sh b.sh
echo "X value is : $x"
#output
# X value is :
```

Comment: You want to source instead of executing: [What is the difference between `sh` and `source`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13786499/1983854). Also, you `export x`, using `x` instead of `$x`.

Comment: But when I'm using source it is saying that file b.sh not found but it is there in my directory

Comment: Describe what exact steps you are taking, since `source b.sh` from the same directory should work without any problem.

Comment: It worked just I've mentioned the entire path like /full_path/b.sh