# Script not working as Command line

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

i've created simple bash script that do the following
:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cf ssh "$1"
```

When I run the command line from the CLI like `cf ssh myapp` its running as expected, but when I run the script like

```
. myscript.sh myapp
```

I got error: **App  not found**

I dont understand what is the difference, I've provided the app name after I invoke the script , what could be missing here ?

**update**

when I run the script with the following its working, any idea why the "$1" is not working ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cf ssh myapp
```

Comment: Why do you source (`.`) the script? Is `cf` an alias, a command, or something else, and where and how is it installed/defined? The error message looks like something from `cf` which is probably not a programming problem as such.

Comment: I dont use `cf` but it looks like you will get in trouble when opening a TTY and try to connect to an other tty via ssh. Did you try `cf ssh` without any programm name, so you can see if it works at all. You could also try to change the instance for your app via `cf -i`, but i am not sure it this will help.

Comment: @tripleee - what do you mean by source (.) the script ? how can I call it diffrent than . myscript app name ? I run the script from the same path that I was able to run the command cf ssh myapp (which works) I just want to create some script that run it...

Comment: @suleiman - yes when I put in the script exactly the command I need like cf ssh myapp its working ... the only diff is that in the script I want to pass a parameter "$1" ...

Comment: when you create a script you can name it like you want. Then you will need to make it executeable `mod +x filename`. You can call Scripts via `./scriptname` or you add a bin folder to home and add some rights to it too. Alternative use the folder `/usr/local/bin` to store scripts and similar files. The files will get called without any point or shlash in front of it then,  By the way. the normal bash declaration is `#!/bin/bash` without env in it.

Comment: The `env` is certainly harmless and a good idea if your script needs to be portable to systems where Bash is not in `/bin`.

Comment: Sourcing is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786499/what-is-the-difference-between-sh-and-source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
. myscript.sh myapp
```

You don't run the script, but you *source* the file named in the first argument. Sourcing means *reading* the file, so it's as if the lines in the file were typed on the command line. In your case what happens is this:

- `myscript.sh` is treates as the file to source and the `myapp` argument is ignored.
- This line is treated as a comment and skipped.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  ```
- This line:

  ```
  cf ssh "$1"
  ```

  is read as it stands. `"$1"` takes the value of `$1` in the calling shell. Possibly - most likely in your case - it's blank.

Now you should know why it works as expected when you *source* this version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cf ssh myapp
```

There's no `$1` to resolve, so everything goes smoothly.

To *run* the script and be able to pass arguments to it, you need to make the file executable and then execute it (as opposed to sourcing). You can execute the script for example this way:

```
./script.bash arg1 arg2
```