# Bash script run from another sets system variables

Tags: bash

I have two scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
./variable2.sh
echo "11111111"
env | grep TEST_ID
```

and:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TEST_ID=1234567890
echo "222222222"
env | grep TEST_ID
```

Result of running it is:

```
./variable.sh
222222222
TEST_ID=1234567890
11111111
```

So looks like if script2 sets variables, they are not seen in script which is running it..
Anyone know how to solve this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: A basic principle of Unix is that a child process cannot alter the environment of its parent.  Therefore, the behavior you see is correct.  If you wanted the definition of of `TEST_ID` to persist, you should not _execute_ `variable2.sh`, you should _source_ it.

Comment: If you run `source ./variable2.sh` then variables will be seen be calling script also.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the difference between `sh` and `source`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786499/what-is-the-difference-between-sh-and-source).