# docker-entrypoint best practice for script execution

Tags: bash, docker, docker-entrypoint

I want to run a couple of scripts on my `docker-entrypoint.sh`;

My question if whether it makes any difference and if it does, what is the recommended way of going about this, regarding the following options:

**A**.

```
${HOMEDIR}/myscript --param1 --param2
```

**B**.

```
bash -c "${HOMEDIR}/myscript --param1 --param2"
```

**C**.

```
source ${HOMEDIR}/myscript --param1 --param2
```

Answer (score 4):

It actually depends on what you are doing and what are you trying to do.

```
${HOMEDIR}/myscript --param1 --param2
```

This one will *execute* the script. When the script is done, any changes that it made to the environment are discarded.

```
bash -c "${HOMEDIR}/myscript --param1 --param2"
```

Running `bash -c "my command here"` vs. just running `my command here` is primarily different in that the former starts a subshell and the latter runs the commands in the current shell.

There are a number of differences in the effects, however:

- Changes to the environment made in the subshell cannot affect the
  parent shell (current directory, values of environment variables,
  function definitions, etc.)
- Variables set in the parent shell that
  has not been exported will be unavailable in the subshell.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276595) is my reference since I did not know much about `bash -c`

```
source ${HOMEDIR}/myscript --param1 --param2
```

When you call source (or its alias .), you insert the script in the current bash process. So you could read variables set by the script.

When you call sh, you initiate a fork (sub-process) that runs a new session of /bin/sh, which is usually a symbolic link to bash. In this case, environment variables set by the sub-script would be dropped when the sub-script finishes.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13786536/5863811) my reference.

TL;DR: If you do not want the bash to keep the changes you want with that scripts you will be running on, I recommend you to use (**A**). If you want the bash to keep the variables and changes, use (**C**). If you want to keep the changes and make the bash run the script on another bash, use (**B**) as I listed the differences between them.