# Making Cobra flag bash completion using remote data

Tags: bash, go, bash-completion, go-cobra

I'm working on a [Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra)-based Go app and I want to have a bash completion for command line flags:

```
$ my-cool-app --some-id=
```

The list of valid values for `--some-id` flag is available by making some HTTP call. How to make such bash completion available using Cobra?

Comment: @Adrian: No, I believe this question is perfectly on-topic here, as the question is how to take advantage of cobra's bash completion feature, when the argument options are determined dynamically.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Bash does not care how you get the valid `--some-id` flags.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: "man bash" knows nothing about cobra's bash completion support. The proper starting place is [here](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/bash_completions.md), with your link as a possible additional resource for advanced customizations (probably irrelevant for this particular question, though).

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann thanks for the hint, but my question is mostly about using Cobra Go package other than programmable bash completion: https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/bash_completions.md

Comment: So you have to make some http  `GET` somewhere, then parse your output with some xml parser or depending on html result, maybe could you use `sed`... You have to post more information about: .1 sample of html result to parse, .2 sample of argument you want to extract, .3 some code you already tried.

Comment: Once your *list of available option* done, you have to use `complete` command, Have a look at [Completion based on Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112493/1765658) or at [how to build a `mrcon` (minecraft remote connexion) with **completion** bash *environment*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58266594/1765658)

Answer (score 0):

### From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58266594/1765658):

Where I create a function with completion for interacting with a [minecraft](/questions/tagged/minecraft) server.

#### .0 Preamble: A function

As for *bounty*:

> Please provide a clear and scalable sample code

There is a nice function intented to create an  URL for *`stackoverflow.com`*:

```
soUrl() { 
    local __so_url='https://stackoverflow.com/'
    if [ "$1" = "-v" ]; then
        printf -v "$2" '%s%s' "$__so_url" "$3"
    else
        printf '%s%s\n' "$__so_url" "$1"
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```
soUrl
https://stackoverflow.com/
soUrl fooBar
https://stackoverflow.com/fooBar
```

or create a *variable*:

```
soUrl -v testvar baz
echo $testvar
https://stackoverflow.com/baz
```

#### .1 Collect available options in an array

> The list of valid values for --some-id flag is available by making some HTTP...

You have to write something like:

```
wget -O - https://somewhere.net/somepath?someoption... |
    sed -ne 's/^.*someRE\(Re2\).*/\1/p'
```

Of course, instead of `wget`, you could use `curl`, `nc` or even `/dev/tcp` or `openssl` ([Login to a site (stackoverflow) by bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223204/1765658))

**But** as you could have to make many tries on command line, use a temporary file in order to avoid stressing web server! Upto you're able to show all your available options.

#### .1b Then create an array:

```
soUrlOpts=($(soUrl -v var;wget -qO - $var | sed -ne '/a href="\//{
     s/.*a href="\/\([^"\/?]*\)[?\/"].*/\1/;H;};${x;:a;
     s/\n\([^\n]\+\)\(\n\(.*\n\|\)\)\1\n/\n\1\2\n/;ta;s/^\n//;s/\n\+/ /g;p;}'))
```

or

```
soUrlOpts=($(
    soUrl -v var
    wget -qO - $var |
    sed -ne '
        /a href="\//{
          s/.*a href="\/\([^"\/?]*\)[?\/"].*/\1/;
          H;
        };
        ${
          x;
         :a;
          s/\n\([^\n]\+\)\(\n\(.*\n\|\)\)\1\n/\n\1\2\n/;
          ta;
          s/^\n//;
          s/\n\+/ /g;
          p;
        }'
))
```

Ensure your variable is correct:

```
declare -p soUrlOpts
declare -a soUrlOpts=([0]="company" [1]="teams" [2]="questions" [3]="jobs"
     [4]="collectives" [5]="users" [6]="advertising" [7]="talent" [8]="help")
```

#### .2 enable completion

```
complete -W "${soUrlOpts[*]}" soUrl
```

Then now, if you write: `soUrl -v testvar q`, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, console must write `uestion`:

```
soUrl -v testvar questions
echo $testvar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
```